# My website works fine, but when I copy the link to Facebook, it says Index of:?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. The website itself works fine. (both with www and without)
When I post the link to Facebook, it doesn't display website title and such. Just Index of: like I posted a FTP link.

The website link is http://www.kastamonuelsanatlari.com/.

The HTML head tags seems okay. Nothing is missing.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify title and other information you want facebook to display, by specifying required tags in your homepage . e.g:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Comment: after you did it, go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and enter your URL and see if facebook can find your meta-data or not. because sometimes facebook caches pages and by putting the url in facebook debugger, it clears the cache for your url

Comment: I checked your code, you have missing information, put og:type as "article"

Comment: Scrape Information
Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now. Thank you. :)

Comment: you also need to specify the url for thumbnail image for your page

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you:

You must publish your main page as index (all lowercase, no extension). After that, all links to that page should be ok. Because the Browser will automatically find your sites index.php or landing page.

Comment: Another reason to be is
The files were not uploaded to the correct folder.  This is if you see no files at all listed.  Check your method of uploading the files and ensure you are uploading to the public_html folder. For your primary domain, the files must be located directly in the public_html folder to display. OR correct usage of meta tags to display index landing page